# Proving a set is finite

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $S=\left\{\frac{1}{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}.$
Show that for every $\beta>0(\beta \in \mathbb{R}),$ the set $S_{\beta}=\{x \in S ; x>\beta\}$ is finite.

So, i've been struggling to prove the above proposition. I have tried a few things.

The first thing i tried was supposing that the set $S_{\beta}$ is not finite. However, that did not lead to a contradiction (at least i could not find one).

After that, i tried to investigate the set $S_{\beta}$ a little further and found that, for $\beta > 2$ where $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $S_{\beta}$ equals the natural numbers.

For example, by picking $\beta = 1/100$, you get:
$$ \\ S_{1/100}=\left\{n \in \mathbb{N}, \frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{100}\right\}=\{1,2, \ldots, 99\}$$

With that in mind, i tried to prove that $S_{\beta}$ equals a finite union of finite sets and therefore should be finite as well. I tried using strong induction for that. Did not go well either.

The last thing i tried was proving that the set $S_{\beta}$ is such that $S_{\beta} \in \mathbb{N}$ and then proving that it is bounded and therefore finite.

Can someone say if i am in the right track? If not, i would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you find a bijection function  $f: S_{\beta}\to \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I tried that after noticing $$\beta=\frac{1}{2} \longmapsto S_{\beta}=\{1\}$$ and by picking other values of $\beta$, but could not find a bijective function.

Comment: @Ramanujan do you have a candidate for that bijective function?

Comment: Lucas, have you considered accepting the answer so that your question would not appear in the "No accepted answer / Not solved questions" list?

Comment: @VIVID I am very sorry, i did not know what i was supposed to do after my question had been aswered. But i just accepted it!! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, if $\beta > 1$, then $S_{\beta}=\{x \in S ; x>\beta\} = \emptyset$ (since $\max(S)=1$)

Now, assume $\beta \in (0,1]$.

By the definition of $S$, we have that $\forall x \in S, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: x = \frac{1}{n}$.

Solving $x>\beta$ now comes down to solve $\frac{1}{n}>\beta$. Trivially, we get $n < \frac{1}{\beta}$.

Since $n$ is a natural number, the number of elements of $S_\beta$ can precisely be given as  $|S_\beta|=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\beta}\right\rfloor$ (which is finite).

Comment: Very interesting! But why did you write that the number of elements of  $S_{\beta}$ can be given "implicitly"?

Comment: Also, i might be missing something, but why can one say that $\left|S_{\beta}\right|=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\beta}\right\rfloor$ is finite?

Comment: @Lucas Sorry, I confused words in my mind (midnight now) :)

Comment: @Lucas For any $\beta$, I can find a number that is greater than $\lfloor \frac{1}{\beta} \rfloor$. So it must be finite.

Comment: hmmm yes! I see now. Can you confirm if, given $\beta$ then $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\beta}\right\rfloor$ + 1 is one of them? I am not very familiar with the floor function )):

Comment: @Lucas Yes, it is actually the most common way to give a greater number :) tl;dr: You're right!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!!! My first experience here at MSE was great!

Comment: @Lucas You are welcome!